# Erro de 404 de uma aplicação Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Estou seguindo a apostila do Caelum. Fiz a aplicação "olá mundo" com Spring MVC, que possui tanto a configuração quanto o respectivo *Controller*.

Porém, quando acesso a URL `localhost:8080/WebSpring/olaMundoSpring` aparece a página de erro 404.

O código da minha aplicação está disponível no GitHub:

> https://github.com/wladyband/SpringComErro/tree/master/WebSpring

quando clico na URL não gera nenhum erro no TomCat

```
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebSpring' did not find a matching property.
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 962 ms
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
Out 07, 2014 10:12:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Out 07, 2014 10:12:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Out 07, 2014 10:12:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
Out 07, 2014 10:12:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Out 07, 2014 10:12:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Out 07, 2014 10:12:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 3562 ms
```

Comment: Comparei seu projeto com um exemplo básico que tenho e não aparenta nenhum problema. Pode ser simplesmente na hora de publicar isso no Tomcat. Poderia postar o log de inicialização do servidor?

Comment: coloquei o log, dá uma olhada para por favor

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui descobrir o problema pelo log. A única coisa que descobri é que o Spring 3 não funciona no Java 8. Não tenho uma versão anterior para testar o projeto agora. Já tentou atualizar para o Spring 4?

Comment: `404` é o erro de `not found`.... verifica se todos os arquivos estão realmente nos `patchs` especificados

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer simplesmente retornar uma string usando como text/plain, favor coloque a anotação @ResponseBody no seu método:

```
@RequestMapping("/olaMundoSpring")
@ResponseBody
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("Executando a lógica com Spring MVC");
    return "ok";
}
```

Pelo que pude perceber o Spring MVC pode estar usando o jsp com view handler, como ele não encontra um ok.jsp ou algo do tipo o mesmo responde com 404.

Comment: Olhando no projeto do GitHub, existe um `ok.jsp`.

Comment: Então neste caso pode-se cogitar problemas com permissão também se for o caso de estar rodando o tomcat no linux, outra possibilidade é o mapeamento do servlet e uma última seria tentar deixar explícito que  está mapeando este caminho (path) para requisições com método GET.

Answer (score 0):

Baixei seu projeto do GitHub e testei a aplicação sem nenhuma alteração: **funcionou!**

Provavelmente é um problema de configuração do Tomcat ou algo relacionado ao ambiente de execução. Usei o JDK 7 e o Tomcat 7 para os testes.

Algo que vai ajudar você a identificar o problema exato, sendo também recomendável para qualquer projeto, é configurar devidamente os logs da aplicação.

Por exmeplo, crie um arquivo nomeado `log4j.xml` diretamente na pasta `src` do projeto com o seguinte conteúdo:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="false"/>
      <param name="file" value="output.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Com isso, informações importantes do Spring serão exibidas no console e gravadas num arquivo de log. Uma delas está destacada a seguir:

> 09 Out 2014 16:37:51  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/olaMundoSpring],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.caelum.tarefas.controller.OlaMundoController.execute()
>
> 09 Out 2014 16:37:51  INFO DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization completed in 1222 ms

Essa informação é o mapeamento da URL do seu *Controller*. Verifique se está tudo correto com as novas informações de log.